# Android: ImageView showing color instead of Image on API 16

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a problem with ImageViews on API 16: The Image (as set in XML) is not shown on older devices. On API 16 the ImageView just displays the accentColor but not the selected Image.

On API 23, for instance, everything works fine.

How can I change this?

**EDIT**: The problem occurs up to API 19. Furthermore, I get an error in the Android Monitor from the Emulator:

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

**EDIT 2**: Ok, I now found out where the problem is: The Image set as "android:src" is used as a mask. Thus, non-transparent png or jpg images will show the background which seems to be the accent color...

Even the Hamburger Icon is orange. However, icons created through the "Image Asset" generator are not affected by this.

[image: Result on API 16]
[image: Result on API 23]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

In the AppTheme (styles.xml) there was

```
 <item name="android:tint">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

This caused the issue. I removed it and now everything works as expected.